# Why do I get TargetInvocationException with BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, backgroundworker

I am working on a C# project where I have a Backgroundworker which does my "expensive work".

In my "DoWork" I want to report progress by "backgroundworker.ReportProgress(some int)". But when my program comes to the call "backgroundworker.ReportProgress(some int)" I get a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException".

How do I fix my problem?

```
private void btnGrap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
        ListsObject listsObject = new ListsObject(filePaths, enumList);
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;//count;
        this.bgrndWorkerSearchMatches.RunWorkerAsync(listsObject);
     }
```

_DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorkerSearchMatches_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            bgrndWorkerSearchMatches.ReportProgress(i);
        }
     }
```

_ProcessChanged:

```
private void bgrndWorkerSearchMatches_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

---

I found the answer:

I created the backgroundworker eventhandler with [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) and did not know that I have to manually set:

```
bgrndWorkerSearchMatches.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Comment: You may want to set the debugger to break on all exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOUND the answer:

i created the backgroundworker eventhandler with visual studio and did not know that i have to manualy set:

```
bgrndWorkerSearchMatches.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

anyway thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 9):

A `TargetInvocationException` is thrown to wrap a different exception that was thrown by the method that was ultimately called.

Check the `InnerException` to find out what happened.

Comment: i tried `code` try { bgrndWorkerSearchMatches.ReportProgress(count); } catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException tiEx) { throw tiEx.InnerException; } `code` but i got exception before inner exception

Comment: Do not `throw InnerException`; it will destroy the stack trace.  Instead, look at the InnerException in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what this ReportProgress() actually does but you'll need to Invoke the the command.

I guess that it'll be something like:

```
private void ReportProgress(int percentage)
{
  this.SetProgressBar(percentage);
}
```

then in the "parent" code that set's up the worker thread:

```
delegate void SetProgressBarCallback(int percentage);
public void SetProgressBar(int percentage)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
            {   
                SetProgressBarCallback d = new SetProgressBarCallback(SetProgressBar);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { percentage});
            }
            else
            {
                this.progressBar1.value = precentage;
            }
        }
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for an example using WinForms.

Comment: If you need the background operation to report on its progress, you can call the ReportProgress method to raise the ProgressChanged event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx

Comment: If you're using that to trigger the change in your progress bar position, you'll still need to check for and use a callback with an invoke to update the UI.